# Multiple Queries GMailApi for list retrieval in Android

Tags: android, gmail, gmail-api

How can one get filtered results using multiple queries with **setQ** in

ListMessagesResponse

```
response = service.users().messages().list(from).setQ("from:*******@gmail.com" +
   ";" + "subject:" + ********).execute();
```

using **GMailApi** for Android ?

Answer (score 0):

```
service.users().messages().list(from).setQ("from:example@gmail.com AND subject:cool subject AND in:INBOX AND ...").execute()
```